# Validating a numeric range without syntax errors when invalid characters are entered

Tags: regex, bash, input, code-injection, sanitization

Hi I have a menu on a bash script. The user must enter a number between 1 and 5. This is my code:

```
read -r data
while [[ ${data} -lt 1 ]] || [[ ${data} -gt 5 ]]; do
    echo "You must enter a number between 1 and 5"
    read -r data
done
```

At first sight is working fine, but the problem happens is if the user enter a "*" or a "/" (and maybe other special chars). They break the script because of a syntactical error. I guess this is "some kind of injection".

How can I do to avoid this "breaking inputs" and keep my data as a number between 1 and 5? Maybe a combination of regex and this? How? Thank you.

**EDIT** The use of a case is not valid for me. For the minimal example I put static numbers but the reality is that 1 and 5 are dynamic numbers so it can't be done using a static case.

Comment: A simple way to get a shell menu is to use bash's builtin `select`.  There are also fancier options (not bash builtin) like options like `iselect` or `dialog`.

Comment: I added an _edit_ on my question. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, this isn't really a syntax error (and, similarly, not really an injection attack) -- the parse tree of your code isn't impacted, it's just trying and failing to treat the value as a number at runtime. An attempt to do `$(rm -rf ~)` or such would have no effect.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis None of `select`, `iselect`, or `dialog` require a `case` statement.  All handle dynamic menu specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a condition checking for digits: `[[ $data =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]`

```
read -r data
while [[ ! $data =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || (( data < 1 || data > 5 )); do
    echo "You must enter a number between 1 and 5"
    read -r data
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative check, and even put it right in the expression that controls the while loop. It can be short enough to be a one-liner.

```
while { read -r -p "Enter a number, 1 to 5. " n && [[ $n = [[:digit:]] ]]; } && (( n < 1 || n > 5 )); do :; done
```

Or for easier reading:

```
while {
    read -r -p "Enter a number, 1 to 5. " n && [[ $n = [[:digit:]] ]]
  } &&
  (( n < 1 || n > 5 )); do
    : Nothing to do here.
done
```

What are the important bits of this?

- The curly braces define a what will amount to a logical expression for evaluation by `while`. If everything within that expression evaluates to true, then proceed with the next, arithmetic test.
- The `:` is a null operation. Nothing actually needs to *run* in the while loop, you just need to keep looping until `$n` evaluates appropriately.
- If the arithmetic expression in the double brackets evaluates to false, then the loop can end, with the value of `n` set as you'd expect. And non-numeric values of `$n` should evaluate to zero within this kind of expression.